# PHP How can I calculate length of Session ID before starting session

Tags: php, session, sessionid

How can I calculate length of PHP session id, based on php.ini values [`session.hash_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-function) and [`session.hash_bits_per_character`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-bits-per-character), and before starting the session.

I want to create and assign custom session id like `session_id($customSessionId);`, before starting session.

In my local machine value of `session.hash_function` is 0 (possible values are '0' for MD5 and '1' for SHA-1) and value of `session.hash_bits_per_character` is 5 (possible values are '4' [0-9, a-f], '5' [0-9, a-v], and '6' [0-9, a-z, A-Z, "-", ","]), and the resulting length of session id is 26.

What will be the length of session id when `session.hash_function` and `session.hash_bits_per_character` have another set of values, which can be calculated before starting session?

I want to calculate session ids with different length on different servers (local, staging or production), and by analyzing default session settings.

> Starting the session and calculating session id is pretty much simpler. But i want to code the code something like:

```
// $length = {code to get length from hash_function and hash_bits_per_character}

// this is my custom function to generate new session id having length $length
$myCustomSessionId = generateCustomSessionId($length);

// assign my custom session id
session_id($myCustomSessionId);

//and finally start the session :)
session_start();
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are all of the session hash algorithms for 5.3.  Use my code at the bottom if you want to try it out on your own server

```
algo        bits   length
md2           4     32
md2           5     26
md2           6     22
md4           4     32
md4           5     26
md4           6     22
md5           4     32
md5           5     26
md5           6     22
sha1          4     40
sha1          5     32
sha1          6     27
sha224        4     56
sha224        5     45
sha224        6     38
sha256        4     64
sha256        5     52
sha256        6     43
sha384        4     96
sha384        5     77
sha384        6     64
sha512        4    128
sha512        5    103
sha512        6     86
ripemd128     4     32
ripemd128     5     26
ripemd128     6     22
ripemd160     4     40
ripemd160     5     32
ripemd160     6     27
ripemd256     4     64
ripemd256     5     52
ripemd256     6     43
ripemd320     4     80
ripemd320     5     64
ripemd320     6     54
whirlpool     4    128
whirlpool     5    103
whirlpool     6     86
tiger128,3    4     32
tiger128,3    5     26
tiger128,3    6     22
tiger160,3    4     40
tiger160,3    5     32
tiger160,3    6     27
tiger192,3    4     48
tiger192,3    5     39
tiger192,3    6     32
tiger128,4    4     32
tiger128,4    5     26
tiger128,4    6     22
tiger160,4    4     40
tiger160,4    5     32
tiger160,4    6     27
tiger192,4    4     48
tiger192,4    5     39
tiger192,4    6     32
snefru        4     64
snefru        5     52
snefru        6     43
snefru256     4     64
snefru256     5     52
snefru256     6     43
gost          4     64
gost          5     52
gost          6     43
adler32       4      8
adler32       5      7
adler32       6      6
crc32         4      8
crc32         5      7
crc32         6      6
crc32b        4      8
crc32b        5      7
crc32b        6      6
salsa10       4    128
salsa10       5    103
salsa10       6     86
salsa20       4    128
salsa20       5    103
salsa20       6     86
haval128,3    4     32
haval128,3    5     26
haval128,3    6     22
haval160,3    4     40
haval160,3    5     32
haval160,3    6     27
haval192,3    4     48
haval192,3    5     39
haval192,3    6     32
haval224,3    4     56
haval224,3    5     45
haval224,3    6     38
haval256,3    4     64
haval256,3    5     52
haval256,3    6     43
haval128,4    4     32
haval128,4    5     26
haval128,4    6     22
haval160,4    4     40
haval160,4    5     32
haval160,4    6     27
haval192,4    4     48
haval192,4    5     39
haval192,4    6     32
haval224,4    4     56
haval224,4    5     45
haval224,4    6     38
haval256,4    4     64
haval256,4    5     52
haval256,4    6     43
haval128,5    4     32
haval128,5    5     26
haval128,5    6     22
haval160,5    4     40
haval160,5    5     32
haval160,5    6     27
haval192,5    4     48
haval192,5    5     39
haval192,5    6     32
haval224,5    4     56
haval224,5    5     45
haval224,5    6     38
haval256,5    4     64
haval256,5    5     52
haval256,5    6     43
```

Here is the code I used to generate them:

```
session_start();

$algos = hash_algos();

foreach ($algos as $key => $algo) {
    ini_set('session.hash_function', $algo);
    for ($i = 4; $i <= 6; $i++) {
        ini_set('session.hash_bits_per_character', $i);
        session_regenerate_id();
        echo $algo . ' - ' . $i . ' - ' . strlen(session_id()) . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code sniplet describing session id length for all available {hash function, bits per char} combination. But I want to get the length of session id BEFORE STARTING SESSION, with the known values `session.hash_function` and `session.hash_bits_per_character`.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a year and a half late. However, here is the answer.

Each of the hashing algorithm returns a fixed length string. It's easy to know that length just computing a hash:

```php
$t = hash('md5', '', True);
print strlen($t)*8; // 8 Bits per char
```

The ini option `session.hash_bits_per_character` indicate how the hashed string (which is a binary string) should be transformed to make it printable and safe for storing. It indicates how many bits from the original hash will be converted to a single character on output. A value of 4 is used to get an hexadecimal output, as each hexadecimal digit represents 4 bits. A value of 6 is Base 64 encoding. 
You can use the information on `session.hash_function`and `session.hash_bits_per_character` to calculate the size of the resulting session id computing a hash and then calculate the final length it will have:

```php
$hash_function = ini_get("session.hash_function");
// Special case: 0=md5 and 1=sha1, anything else should be the 
// name of the hashing algorithm
if($hash_function==0) {
    $hash_function="md5";
}
elseif($hash_function==1) {
    $hash_function="sha1";
};

$hash_bits = ini_get("session.hash_bits_per_character");
$t = hash($hash_function, "", True);
print "Algorithm: $hash_function\n";
print "Hash Length (chars): " . strlen($t) . "\n";
print "Bits Per Char: $hash_bits\n";
print "Final Length (chars): " . ceil(strlen($t)*8/$hash_bits) . "\n";
```

```
Algorithm: md5
Hash Length (chars): 16
Bits Per Char: 5
Final Length (chars): 26
```